# Directive attribute unit test

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the below directive

```
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            getLink: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'abc.html',
        controller: 'abcController'
    };
```

Inside abcController i have this below function that i want to test.

```
$scope.printData = function()
    {
        $scope.getLink().then(
            function(url) {
                $window.open(url);
                $window.focus();
            },
            function(response) {
                $log.error('Error opening  ' + response);
            }
        );

    };
```

i am trying to test the printData function, this is the below test i am trying to write.

```
it('should print the visualizer report', inject(function(mockObjects) {
        scope.mockData = mockObjects.mockData;
        element = angular.element("<my-directive data='mockData'  get-link='test'/>");
        compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        var childScope = scope.$$childTail;
        childScope.getPdfLink = getPdfLink();
        childScope.printData();
    }));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  “$scope.getLink is not a function
```

Anything wrong that i am doing ?

Comment: we need to see the directive's html code

Comment: If you want to test the printData() function, which is part of abcController, why don't you write a unit test for abcController instead of writing a unit test for the directive? Where and how is `scope.test` defined?

Comment: Our team is already following the above approach for rest of the tests. We are able to test the other function is the controller and able to call using $$childTail.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You're passing "test" as the get-link attribute. The message says that getLink is not a function. So the problem is with "test" not being a function. So where and how is test being defined?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function with '&' as describe on [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            getLink: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'abc.html',
        controller: 'abcController'
    };


<div your-directive get-link="yourDelegatedMethod()"></div>
```